# Как скейлить картинку без anti-aliasing?

Tags: php, изображения, imagemagick

Когда скейлю картинку используя

```
$result->scaleImage($result->getImageWidth()*1.1, $result->getImageHeight() * 1.1);
```

появляюься вот такие штуки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно чтобы после получлось без них
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам, наверно, в векторе работать надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменить размер картинки без anti-aliasing'а можно так:
1. sampleImage
2. resizeImage с фильтром типа FILTER_POINT, FILTER_BOX

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]